# Using export command to alter PATH from shell script file

Tags: bash, unix, ember.js, path, vagrant

I am setting up a [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) box (VM) to mimic a server. The idea is that you initialize the VM by running one command and it provisions itself using a single bash script file, "bootstrap.sh".

I am trying to run ember on my VM.

So in the script file, I install node, nvm, npm, and all other kinds of dependencies and stuff. Just for reference, this is what the file looks like:

```
echo "installing node version manager"
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.24.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

# EMBER CLI & DEPENDENCIES ...

# Install node.js
echo "Installing node.js"
nvm install stable
nvm use stable

# Symlink node to node.js
echo "node symlink"
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

# Install npm
echo "Installing node package manager"
apt-get install -y npm

# Install Ember CLI
echo "Installing Ember CLI"
npm install -g ember-cli

# Install Bower
echo "Installing bower"
sudo npm install -g bower

# Install watchman from source
apt-get install -y autoconf automake
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
cd

# Install Phantom.js
echo "Installing Phantom.js"
sudo npm install -g phantomjs

# Do some weird path thing that makes npm find Ember (?)
echo "Creating path for node modules"
export PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

But when i run `ember s` it says "ember: command not found".

If i rerun this line in the VM:

```
export PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

then it works.

So it seems that `export PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH` does not work form the shell script file, but it does work if you run it from the command-line (on the VM via ssh)

Why is this happening and how can I make this command run the same from the script file, as if it were run from command-line?

Comment: It does work but it doesn't persist, so as soon as that shell session ends, that variable goes with it. You need to modify the path in the `~/.bashrc` file most likely.

Comment: Are you sourcing your script file, or simply running it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to have a relative path name in `PATH`.  Any binaries will only be found when you are in the parent directory of `node_modules`.  I don't think running the `export` again made any difference; you just happened to be in the right directory.

Assuming `node_path` is in your home directory, try

```
export PATH=$HOME/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

where the beef is adding `$HOME/` in front of `node_modules`.